# Object required: 'objShell.NameSpace(...)' Sompin' ain't right

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that is searching for files, copying them and then zipping. The problem area is at the end where I create a vbs file within the batch file and then run it. Here's my code:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM ** Loops through each arugment in the input file

set fileList=sys-conf.txt, CNCIDNUM.txt, cnc-para.txt,pitch.txt,OPRT_HIS.txt,TOOLOFST.TXT,macro.txt,3D-INTER.txt,ATCMagazine_,Makino_AtdAxis_CMN_,Makino_AtdAxis_Duty_,Makino_Atdspindle_,Makino_IOlink_setting,Makino_MMS_,Makino_Parameter_,Makino_QAC_CurveFit_,Makino_QAC_Override_,Makino_QAC_Setting_,PalletMagazine_,MCA_selectData.txt

:getDestination
set /p destination=Enter the destination Folder to copy the files :
if not exist !destination! goto getDestination

for %%A in ("%~f0\..") do set "fol=%%~nxA"

set m_dd=%date%_%time%
set m_dd=%m_dd: =%
set m_dd=%m_dd::=_%
set m_dd=%m_dd:/=_%
set m_dd=%m_dd:.=_%
set m_d=%m_dd:~3,-3%

set dest=!destination!\%fol%_%m_d%
set op=%dest%.zip

if not exist !dest! (
    echo !dest!
    mkdir !dest!
) else (
    :getConfirm
    set _confirm=Folder Already Exists..Continue [Y/N] :
    if /i "!_confirm!"=="n" (
    timeout /t 3
    echo "Script Execution Terminated"
    exit
    )
    if /i not "!_confirm!"=="n" if /i not "!_confirm!"=="y" (
     goto getConfirm
    )
)

for %%F in (%fileList%) do (
echo Checking for the file...: %%F

REM ** Check whether the file is present in the directory --> Find command is used for handling "No files found"
for /f %%H in ('dir /s /b *%%F* 2^>nul ^| find /C /V ""') do (

REM ** If No files are found ask user confirmation
if %%H==0 (
:input
set /p confirm=File Not Found..Do you want to continue [Y/N] :

if /i "!confirm!"=="y" (
 for /f %%B in ('dir /s /b *%%F*') do (
 echo File Found: %%B
 copy %%B "!dest!"
 )
)
if /i "!confirm!"=="n" (
 timeout /t 7
 echo "Script Execution terminated"
 exit
)
if /i not "!confirm!"=="n" if /i not "!confirm!"=="y" (
 goto input
)

) else (
 REM ** If files are found copy them to the destination
 for /f %%B in ('dir /s /b *%%F*') do (
 echo File Found: %%B
 copy %%B "!dest!"
 )
)
)
)
@echo off>zip.vbs
@echo 'Get command-line arguments.>>zip.vbs
@echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments>>zip.vbs
@echo InputFolder = objArgs(0)>>zip.vbs
@echo ZipFile = objArgs(1)>>zip.vbs
@echo REM>>zip.vbs
@echo 'Create empty ZIP file.>>zip.vbs
@echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar)>>zip.vbs
@echo REM>>zip.vbs
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")>>zip.vbs
@echo REM>>zip.vbs
@echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items>>zip.vbs
@echo REM>>zip.vbs
@echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)>>zip.vbs
@echo REM>>zip.vbs
@echo 'Required!>>zip.vbs
@echo wScript.Sleep 2000>>zip.vbs
CScript  zip.vbs  !dest!  .\success.zip
```

The error output is this:

```
E:\somefolder\zip.vbs(11, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime e
rror: Object required: 'objShell.NameSpace(...)'
```

My "!dest!" and ".\success.zip" are purely guesses and I base the last chunk of code on the 2nd answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili), which details how it can be done.

Ideally I would like the zip file to just be in whatever the current directory is and I don't care what the zip file name is.

Answer (score 1):

The below actually works.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM ** Loops through each arugment in the input file

set fileList=data

:getDestination
set /p destination=Enter the destination Folder to copy the files :
if not exist !destination! goto getDestination

for %%A in ("%~f0\..") do set "fol=%%~nxA"

set m_dd=%date%_%time%
set m_dd=%m_dd: =%
set m_dd=%m_dd::=_%
set m_dd=%m_dd:/=_%
set m_dd=%m_dd:.=_%
set m_d=%m_dd:~3,-3%

set dest=!destination!\%fol%_%m_d%
set op=%dest%.zip

if not exist !dest! (
    mkdir !dest!
) else (
    :getConfirm
    set _confirm=Folder Already Exists..Continue [Y/N] :
    if /i "!_confirm!"=="n" (
    timeout /t 3
    echo "Script Execution Terminated"
    exit
    )
    if /i not "!_confirm!"=="n" if /i not "!_confirm!"=="y" (
     goto getConfirm
    )
)

for %%F in (%fileList%) do (
echo Checking for the file...: %%F

REM ** Check whether the file is present in the directory --> Find command is used for handling "No files found"
for /f %%H in ('dir /s /b *%%F* 2^>nul ^| find /C /V ""') do (

REM ** If No files are found ask user confirmation
if %%H==0 (
:input
set /p confirm=File Not Found..Do you want to continue [Y/N] :

if /i "!confirm!"=="y" (
 for /f %%B in ('dir /s /b *%%F*') do (
 echo File Found: %%B
 copy %%B "!dest!"
 )
)
if /i "!confirm!"=="n" (
 timeout /t 7
 echo "Script Execution terminated"
 exit
)
if /i not "!confirm!"=="n" if /i not "!confirm!"=="y" (
 goto input
)

) else (
 REM ** If files are found copy them to the destination
 for /f %%B in ('dir /s /b *%%F*') do (
 echo File Found: %%B
 copy %%B "!dest!"
 )
)
)
call :zippy !dest!

)

:zippy
echo InputFolder = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)>zip.vbs
echo zipFileName = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)>>zip.vbs
echo With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")>>zip.vbs
echo zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFileName)>>zip.vbs
echo sourceFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(InputFolder)>>zip.vbs
echo With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)>>zip.vbs
echo .Write Chr(80) ^& Chr(75) ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, chr(0))>>zip.vbs
echo End With>>zip.vbs
echo End With>>zip.vbs
echo With CreateObject("Shell.Application")>>zip.vbs
echo .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sourceFolder).Items>>zip.vbs
echo Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = _>>zip.vbs
echo .NameSpace(sourceFolder).Items.Count>>zip.vbs
echo WScript.Sleep 10000>>zip.vbs
echo Loop>>zip.vbs
echo End With>>zip.vbs
CScript zip.vbs "%1" .\success.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a VBS file and calling it, you could use PowerShell `Compress-Archive`. This whole thing would be easier if it were a PowerShell script. If you absolutely need to keep it as a batch script then here is an example that calls PowerShell at the end.

I greatly simplified your code while keeping the behavior the same.

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: ** Loops through each arugment in the input file
set fileList=sys-conf.txt,CNCIDNUM.txt,cnc-para.txt,pitch.txt,OPRT_HIS.txt,TOOLOFST.TXT,macro.txt,3D-INTER.txt,ATCMagazine_,Makino_AtdAxis_CMN_,Makino_AtdAxis_Duty_,Makino_Atdspindle_,Makino_IOlink_setting,Makino_MMS_,Makino_Parameter_,Makino_QAC_CurveFit_,Makino_QAC_Override_,Makino_QAC_Setting_,PalletMagazine_,MCA_selectData.txt

:: You can pass the directory as an argument
if [%1]==[] (
:getDestination
    set /p destination=Enter the destination Folder to copy the files :
    if not exist !destination! goto getDestination
) else (
    set destination=%1
)

for %%A in (.) do set "fol=%%~nxA"

set m_dd=%date%_%time%
set m_dd=%m_dd: =%
set m_dd=%m_dd::=_%
set m_dd=%m_dd:/=_%
set m_dd=%m_dd:.=_%
set m_d=%m_dd:~3,-3%

set dest=%destination%\%fol%_%m_d%
set op=%dest%.zip

echo Testing if destination exists: %dest%
if not exist %dest% (
    mkdir "%dest%"
) else (

:getConfirm

    set _confirm=Continue? [Y/N] :
    if /i "!_confirm!"=="n" (
        timeout /t 3
        echo Script Execution Terminated
        exit
    )

    if /i not "!_confirm!"=="y" (
        echo Invalid response. Enter only 'y' or 'n'
        goto getConfirm
    )
)

for %%F in (%fileList%) do (
    copy "%%F" "%dest%"
)

echo Running PowerShell to compress: %dest%
powershell "Compress-Archive -Path """%dest%\*""" -DestinationPath """%op%""""
```